# div element with different elements in it. Want to hide whole element on page load. want to hide loaded elemnt by clicking btn and show hidden elemnt

Tags: html, css, element, hidden

here is my div code and my file type is .php

these are div elements that I want to hide.

i use different methods with id and class also with javascript but my issue is not resolved

````
        <div class="qamar-container">
            <div class="content-section">
                <h1>AB & MIB Traders</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="button-section">
                <button>AB</button>
                <button>ABC</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>```

if need any other information please tell me.
````

Comment: Hi, please add the JavaScript and CSS attempts you made in the. question

Comment: Please be more clear to receive a valid answer.

Comment: thanks all of you i found the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here are the steps by which my issue is resolved.

***CSS Styles***

```
            display:none;
        }
```

***javascript***

```
    jQuery('#qamar-ab').on('click', function(event) {        
         jQuery('#ab').toggle('show');
         jQuery('#qamar').toggle('hide');
    });
});
```